# Sign of result of addition in floating point arithmetic

Tags: math, floating-point, ieee-754

How can I determine the sign of the result of an addition in floating-point arithmetic?

I'm not sure if I've seen any info about it in standard IEEE-754, but my guess is: implement addition and subtraction of non-negative numbers and then change sign of result according to needs. Is it right?

Comment: IEEE-754 floats have a sign bit that's 1 for negative and 0 for positive numbers, so just check the MSB?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes, but in the article I read there were no manipulations with MSB of result, so I'm not sure...

Comment: Your post does not talk about any articles. It asks how to determine the sign of a number that is the result of an addition. If you want to know how you add two IEEE-754 floating point numbers in a way that the sign is correct, that is a completely different question and you need to [edit] your post to [make that clear](/help/how-to-ask), while bearing in mind that there are loads of pages on the web that explain how IEEE arithmetic works, so you're going to have to show that you did your research and found _nothing_ that answered your question already.

Answer (score 1):

If the mathematical sum of two numbers is non-zero, the floating-point result has the same sign as the mathematical sum, even if the floating-point result is zero. The latter is due to IEEE 754-2019 4.3, first paragraph: “Inexact numeric floating-point results always have the same sign as the unrounded result.”

If the mathematical sum is zero, then, per IEEE 754-2019 6.3, third paragraph:

- If the sum is +0 + +0, the sign is +, and, if the sum is −0 + −0, the sign is −.
- Otherwise, if the rounding method is toward-negative, the sign is −.
- Otherwise, the sign is +.